# could not create script recorder , see log Invalid keystore format

Tags: jmeter

While running jmeter , getting the below error , couldnt find solution pls help

[image]

It worked the other day, i was expecting to start the recorder and record requests

Comment: Worked for me by installing latest java version , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) it generates `proxyserver.jks` file in JMeter's "bin" folder.

If the file got corrupt somehow just delete it and next time you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder it will be regenerated.

If you're using a custom keystore check the properties responsible for [Test Script Recorder certificate configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert).

Also be aware that you can record a JMeter test plan using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Thanks, using blazemeter as suggested , and the other one also worked after installing latest java